# How to set Zooming limit of jfreechart?

Tags: java, jfreechart

I am using jfreeChart for creating gnattChart .I want to set some limit on the NumberAxis to limit the Zooming.
for example lower limit=1000 and upper limit=2000;
here I want that My NumberAxis should display values between 1000 to 2000,and I want to zoom the graph between these two  values.
I do not want unnecessary values while zooming the graph, in this case value below 1000 and values above 2000 are unnecessary for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently not supported by JFreeChart. The caller should take care of limiting zooming in/out. If you use a ChartPanel, have a look at the actionPerformed() method and the various ZOOM_*_COMMANDs.

Also [searching the JFreeChart forum](http://www.jfree.org/forum/search.php?keywords=%2bzoom%20%2blimit) brings up some related posts that might help.

Hope that helps,
- martin